# Cannot change the default sharing option for a SharePoint Online site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-sharing

In our SharePoint Online tenancy we currently have the external sharing option for the Team Site template set to "New & Existing Guests" while also having our Communication Site template set to "No External Access". We now have the requirement to change the Communication Site template to "Existing Guests".

I have looked on the SharePoint Online Admin centre and cannot find where this can be changed. I've also looked at Microsofts documentation for PowerShell and cannot find anything that would allow us to change this. Does anyone know how we can change the default external sharing setting for the Communication Site Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft, by default, the default sharing setting for Microsoft 365 group-connected team sites is "New and existing guests." The default for communication sites and classic sites is "Only people in your organization." I don't think it can be changed.

[image]

References:

[External sharing overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview)

[Set SharePoint Online Default Sharing Link To People With Existing Access](https://lightningtools.com/blog/sharepoint-default-sharing-link-people-with-existing-access)